# If else statement in gui buttons in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

The problem i am having is that i want this code to run in a way that when i pressed the button it  only does what is in the command but it also run the def ad() function in continuity how can i fix this problem that it only runs the button function when i pressed it otherwise the def ad() keeps running only stops when the button is pressed.

```
root=Tk()
root.geometry('1600x900')
root.configure(bg='black')

def clicker():
    global pop1
    pop1=Toplevel(root)
    pop1.geometry('1600x900')
    
    global pic
    pic=PhotoImage(file='location.png')
    label_pop = Label(pop1, image=pic)
    label_pop.grid()
    pop1.overrideredirect(1)
    pop1.after(5000, lambda: pop1.destroy())

btn1 =Button(root, image=location, borderwidth=0, bg='black', command=clicker)
btn1.pack(pady=10)

def ad():
    global pop
    pop = Toplevel(root)
    pop.geometry('1600x900')
    pop.overrideredirect(1)

    pic = PhotoImage(file=next(imagelist))  # get next image using next()

    label_pop = Label(pop, image=pic)
    label_pop.grid()
    label_pop.image = pic  # save reference of image to avoid garbage collection

    root.after(5000, pop.destroy)
    root.after(15000, ad)


root.after(10000, ad)

root.overrideredirect(1)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `def ad()` is not a function, `ad` is. what exactly doesn't work as you expect?

Comment: i want ad() to stop whenever i pressed the button

Comment: stop like it doesn't run after you release the button or pause so that it doesn't work only while you have pressed the button? because the latter might be a little more complicated

Comment: i want it to pause when the button pressed the function inside the button executes and then it resumes ad()

Comment: so should that `Toplevel` freeze and it should stop those scheduled calls and then schedule again?

Comment: no it did not is there anything that can be helpful?

Comment: do you want to pause the schedule? so that when you press and hold that button it may take more than those 15 seconds for it to call `ad` again?

Comment: yes i want to pause the schedule

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick example showing how you can "pause" an `after` call. What you do is measure how much time has passed before holding down the button and then you subtract that from how the time it should be scheduled after and when released schedule another `after` with that left time. So now while you hold down the button it will cancel the previous after call and schedule a new one with left time when you release the button:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import time


DELAY_MS = 5000
time_ms, last = DELAY_MS, 0
after_id = None


def window():
    global after_id, last, time_ms
    time_ms = DELAY_MS
    top = tk.Toplevel()
    top.attributes('-topmost', True)

    root.after(2000, top.destroy)
    after_id = root.after(DELAY_MS, window)
    last = time.perf_counter() * 1000


def pause_after():
    global time_ms
    if after_id is None:
        return
    root.after_cancel(after_id)
    passed_time = time.perf_counter() * 1000 - last
    left = int(time_ms - passed_time)
    if left > 0:
        time_ms = left
        print(time_ms)


def unpause_after():
    global after_id, last
    if after_id is None:
        return
    after_id = root.after(time_ms, window)
    last = time.perf_counter() * 1000


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('500x400')

btn = tk.Button(root, text='Pause', command=unpause_after)
btn.bind('<Button-1>', lambda _: pause_after())
btn.pack()

root.after(1000, window)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: is it possible to use if else in this situation?

Comment: Basically i am making a gui in which different ads pop up in the form of pictures and it has 2 buttons the problem occurs when i pressed the button it overlaps the ad's images which i don't want. So is there anything you can help?